# Asp .Net Core WebApi : 2nd http call on exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fire-and-forget

I'm writing one Webapi where I've to call a 2nd endpoint of HTTP when the first HTTP endpoint fails. However, for the second HTTP call, my application shouldn't block the main thread and should return an unsuccessful result. My HTTP client is already equipped with Polly retry policies, and after retries, I want to call the 2nd URL silently without blocking the main thread.
My code looks like below.

```
public class Request 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }       
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
   private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
   private readonly Ilogger _appLogger;
   private readonly string _url1="www.somedomain.com/api1";
   private readonly string _url2="www.somedomain.com/api2";

   Service(IHttpClientFactory factory,Ilogger logger)
   {
     _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
     _appLogger = logger;
   }

   public async Task<Result> Send(Request request)
   { 
        try
        {
         using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
         using HttpRequestMessage httpRequest =new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _url1);
         var req = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Request>(body);
         var stringContent = new StringContent(req, Encoding.UTF8, "json");
         var result = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
         var resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(resultContent));
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            if (ex is OperationCanceledException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
            {
              //Second call needed but don't want to hold the result 
              // Task.Run(async ()=> await Log(request))    //Approach 1 
              // Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await Log(request)) //Approach 2
              // HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => Log(request).ConfigureAwait(false)); //Approach 3
              // QueuedHostedService defined here [Microsoft][1]
              // var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Log(request).ConfigureAwait(false)); //Approach 4 by hangfire [Hangfire][2]
              // Custome singleton suggested here // [CustomImplementation][1]
            }

            //No 2nd call needed
            await _appLogger.LogAsync(new ExceptionLog(ex));
            return Result{IsSuccess=false;};
         }
   }
   public async Task Log(Request request)
   {
        try
        {
         using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
         using var httpRequest =new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _url2);
         var req = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Request>(body);
         var stringContent = new StringContent(req, Encoding.UTF8, "json");
         var result = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
         var resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(resultContent));
          await _appLogger.LogAsync("2nd call successful.",result );

         }
         
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
          
            await _appLogger.LogAsync("2nd call failed",ex);
            
         }
   }
}
```

I was looking for many solutions but am now confused between them.
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio
[2]: https://www.hangfire.io/
[3]: https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/10/14/fire-and-forget-in-aspnet-core-with-dependency-alive

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you're looking for is a `fire and forget` mechanism, that should work independently with current scope.

We all know that as soon as `HttpRequest` finish their response, current scope including all the service that we use, would be dispose(default scope level behavior). So, let imagine 2nd call came back later, after the origin http request finish, everything would already disposed and clear out. Nasty error...

Take a look at [this](https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/10/14/fire-and-forget-in-aspnet-core-with-dependency-alive), and process it in your catch block and things should be good.

Another approach is make use of [Background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), the idea is creating a queue that contain necessary information to let the background scan and process them, let say for whatever interval rate we want.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, however, I may need some scoped information e.g logger to log the result. [This](https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/10/14/fire-and-forget-in-aspnet-core-with-dependency-alive) looks an ideal candidate to me also, but I'm not sure about background service (will that be overengineering to the simple problem).

Comment: For logging stuff, we should should log something out before call the 2nd request, and pass some unique thing to the `fire and forget` mechanism like `CorrelationId` or whatever we need to search the log. There's no way to keep the whole logging context with forget mechanism, cause it tightly couple with current scope.

Comment: And for `background service`, it's not overengineering at all. We can totally make our own with less than 100 lines of code for the whole `background service`, and a few more line to queue information where we need to process them. Actually, under 100 lines of code seems not to be an engineering problem... right ? - One thing I absolutely aggree, `Hangfire` should be overkill for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide a breakdown of your possible approaches:

**- Fire and forget call:**
It does work, is the easiest to implement, but it doesn't provide any guarantee or visibility that the code executed. Any exception inside a fire and forget method will be swallowed. If your application stops during the execution of a fire and forget method, you can't get any retry attempt. Use this approach if the call is not mandatory.

**- Hangfire:** It does what you want, it has several options like defining retry policies and setting how many parallel executions you can have. It supports several different storages, including in memory, SQL and NoSQL. Personally, I'm a big fan of HangFire and think it is the most robust approach while being easy to implement. However, it does add a dependency that you might have to discuss with the rest of your team.

**- Hosted Service:**
I doesn't do what you want out of the box, as a Hosted Service is more like an app within an app. You can use it to build a custom persistent job execution, but you'll be pretty much reinventing a subset of Hangfire features. It is by far the most complex approach, and I'd avoid it if possible.

Comment: Yes, regarding `HostedService` i find it a little complex to do. Regarding `Hangfire` i checked and found there is one in-memory store available, but mentioned not to use it for production [here](https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage) and I cannot use sql server or any other backend.

Comment: @MaheshJadhav using in memory storage means you'll lose enqueued jobs if your application shuts down. This is true in any in memory approach you take. How to you intend to persist execution if you can't use a storage?

Comment: I wish if hangfire provides IHostedService implementation for.net web API so that cleanup could have been efficiently handled when shutting down the application. In my case, I'll only trigger the job if I get an exception and in any application, it's very often but not every time.

Comment: @MaheshJadhav you can tell your application to wait for Hangfire when shutting down. But that only works if your application is exiting cleanly. If your application exit unexpectedly your cleanup code is not guaranteed to run, not even with IHostedService. Are you ok with the 2nd call not running?

Comment: I don't think the use of any dependent service like SQL or other store is allowed due to restrictions and compliance. Also at this point, recommending this and getting approval is a tedious task. I do agree that Hangfire will make it very easy and flexible. Sometimes you've to live up with what options are left with you.

Comment: @MaheshJadhav I just wanted to make it clear to you that, with any approach you take, unless there's a storage, you will eventually lose a method call. If that's acceptable to your case, then it's not wrong to not use a permanent storage. If that's not acceptable, then you have no option but go through whatever bureaucracy to get your storage approved. What you can't do is turn a blind eye and pretend that it is guaranteed to execute.